# Javascript convert string to tab of float

Tags: javascript

**how can I convert string variables to tab of float ?**

I have a strange problem using a plugin : flot. I'm trying to draw a graph from data i've received from a server. The problem is that the plugin doesn't take values as string.

For exemple if I do this :

```
values=[[-955, 0.13325974],[-880, 0.23449805],[-795, 0.24322645],[-720, -0.008947457]];
$.plot(graphPersonnel, values);
```

It work, but if I do this it doesnt :

```
values="[[-955, 0.13325974],[-880, 0.23449805],[-795, 0.24322645],[-720, -0.008947457]]";
$.plot(graphPersonnel, values);
```

The problem is that I receive values from my server from a string and I extract them this way :

```
message = getGraph(); // = some_useless_string[[-955, 0.13325974],[-880, 0.23449805],[-795, 0.24322645],[-720, -0.008947457]]
values = message.replace("some_useless_string", "");
```

So I would need to convert it from string to tab of arrays. How could i do that ?

Thx

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 1):

You're getting JSON data off the server as a string. simply parse the JSON using JSON.parse, and you'll be good to go:

```js
var values="[[-955, 0.13325974],[-880, 0.23449805],[-795, 0.24322645],[-720, -0.008947457]]";

var valArray = JSON.parse(values);

console.log(valArray);
```

But yeah, reading the javascript docs is always a good plan.